# Issue with Julia build on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: installation, julia, failed-installation

I am attempting to install Julia on my Samsung Series 7 laptop, which has OS Windows 7 64-bit. Instructions on how to do this are located at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md, under the section "Compiling with MinGW/MSYS2".

Step 4-ii says to run the following command in MSYS2:

```
contrib/windows/get_toolchain.sh 64
```

When I run this command, I get the following error:

```
error: this script requires having 7z installed
```

I have no idea how to get around this. I already had 7zip installed on my computer, but I reinstalled it and am still having the issue. Later, the build step (step 4-iv in the link), which says to run the following command in MSYS2

```
make -j 4
```

also fails, giving me the error

```
bash: make: command not found
```

I suspect this is because of the earlier failure in step 4-ii, though I can't be sure.

My question: How do I get around these issues to get a good working version of Julia?

Incidentally, the immediate reason I am trying to do this is because I want to do the Julia tutorial located at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWkgEddb4-A&feature=youtu.be&list=PLP8iPy9hna6T0dEHtj0GZymvT6ODIJWj0. I tried to just download the regular Julia installation located at http://julialang.org/downloads/ to do this, but it became apparent as I started going through the tutorial that that a more substantial Julia build was required, and I think this is the one that I need.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Julia! A couple questions: is there any indication prior to step 4-ii that a dependency might be missing, like warnings or build errors or anything? I'd go back a few steps and make sure you have MinGW and CMake setup okay. Also 7zip can be used both as a GUI and a command line tool, so it may be possible you have the GUI installed but not the cmd tools? I'd also be curious what you mean by a "substantial" build? From what I watched of the tutorial it didn't appear they were doing anything that the standard build couldn't handle, it's what I use and haven't had (m)any problems.

Comment: The same person who gave that presentation at SciPy held more recently [an excellent Julia workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQ1y5NUD_RI) at JuliaCon 2015. At the start of the video he shows a simple way of setting up an instance of Julia that can be used to follow along the tutorial, using [juliabox.org](https://www.juliabox.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Prior to step 4-ii there were not any warnings/errors. I check my MinGW and CMake installations, they are fine. The issue could be the command lin thing that you mentioned, I've been looking into that and there does seem to be confusion around that.I think you may be right about not needing to go beyond the standard build, I've been retrying that with greater success this time after I installed a few other packages.